# Build external libraries for iOS and Android projects with cmake in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cmake

I want to use SOCI C++ library - http://soci.sourceforge.net/ in my cocos2d-x project (iOS and Android). It requires CMake flags to be configured -  http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/3.2/installation.html.

Is there way to add external lib with CMake flags in cocos2d-x?

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d-x v3 has cmake build template with every project.
If you are comfortable with cmake build scripts, edit the cmake file to your liking.